# Is paid heroku faster than free version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently developing a rails3.2 app and finding Heroku load times exceptionally slow. Can someone please tell me if this is what is to be expected with a paid server on Heroku?

Comment: Load time will probably slow if your app has not received connections for a while, and you are connecting to it since then

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no actual speed difference between paid Heroku and free.  As others have mentioned, your app will "spin down" after a period of inactivity on the free service, and this does not happen on any level of paid service. The only other performance difference is that your app can only handle as many concurrent connections as there are dynos - so if two users connect to your free app at the same time, one has to wait for the other's request to finish (this is usually minimal and shouldn't bother anything until you start to get some traffic).

That having been said, you should also consider when your app is slow. If it's slow for the first request, and spry for requests after that, it's the spin-down issue and nothing to worry about. If all requests are slow, that's probably something that needs to be troubleshot in the app (though a paid Heroku account is probably still not the answer).

Comment: Heroku really needs to do something about the spin down and simultaneous request handling.

Comment: @Abram: I'm agree with you. Unfortunately this is just "free-service", and we cannot complain on something comes free :P

Comment: Worth noting that Heroku now has 1X, 2X and XL dynos. 2X have more resources (but still shared) and XL gets you a significantly larger allocation that's not shared. It isn't cheap, but it's likely to be quicker: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/2/3/heroku-xl

Comment: @Abram They have done something about it. They've offered a paid tier ; )

Answer (score 19):

The free version [idles](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-idling) after a period of inactivity. This is probably the slowness you are experiencing. The paid version does not idle.

Comment: I had the same problem, the first request was always very slow but I found a nice tool ( http://www.wekkars.com ) that fixed my problem.

Comment: Yeah, A hobby dyno is powerful enough

Answer (score 6):

I went through the same problem a couple of days ago and it seems like the best fix for this is to install the NewRelic addon to your heroku app. The NewRelic addon keeps on monitoring your web application (subsequently making periodic request to your app), ensuring that the dyno stays active. This effectively cancels out the idling issue.

One thing to note though, its probably best to install the addon only after you have finish a huge part of your development and are actively testing the app with beta users. 
Also, note that in the paid version of heroku, the dyno never idles (as per their documentation). Hope this helps.

Comment: Why is it so important to have finished a huge development part?!

Comment: @StephanSchielke There's no point in keeping your dyno alive 24/7 when you don't use it actively